# SignalR timeout errors

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have started seeing these errors in the javascript console recently, although using SignalR for a long time. So maybe due to a version update in the client microsoft/signalR

```
Utils.js:218 [2021-07-28T15:36:22.247Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.
```

So I added these lines to the client code (commented newly added), this reduced the frequency of the errors, but those did not go away:

```
    connectSignalRHub() {
    const liveMarginHub = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(buildSignalRUrl('liveUpdateHub'))
        .withAutomaticReconnect() // newly added
        .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Error)
        .build();

    // newly added
    liveMarginHub.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 3; // Three minutes
    liveMarginHub.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 6; // Six minutes
```

The backend is ASP.NET core. I see there are options of specifying timeouts there as well, like

```
        sc.AddSignalR(c =>
        {
            c.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            c.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            c.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        });
```

But is this a right thing to do? I am just trying to make the timeout error message go away from the UI console.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Try using the latest patched version of the npm package for 3.1 or 5.0. Also, `c.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;` is going to cause issues, it basically means, never send the keepalive to the client so the client will timeout the connection after being idle for the serverTimeoutInMilliseconds duration.

Comment: @Brennan I was using   "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.8" which seems to be latest version. Now I have tried   6.0.0-preview.6.21355.2 but the error messages do not stop.